# Process.Start, do nothing if input file == 0 kb

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem, I use Process.Start to launch an executable, although is it possible to say: if input.txt == 0kb do nothing, else execute process ?

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c test.exe -f input.txt > output.txt").WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) to get the size of the input file and only run the process if it is larger than 0:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("input.txt");
if(fi.Length > 0)
{
  Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c test.exe -f input.txt > output.txt").WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, In my case this is part of a while loop in Main, I added "else" but how can I escape the loop, so if the value is for example 2kb, exit the loop and start from the begginning of the loop again

Comment: @Ben - look at the [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx) statement.

Comment: Hi, looks pretty brief at best, will post a question. Thanks for your help :)